# Turn Philips Hue Lamp on via API

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
#url's
urlLiOn = 'https://192.168.1.101/api/WBhm7KR52YMWVnDIz9HMeqjHC2VZytaCVmV8YP3C/groups/Schlafzimmer/action'
urlLiOff = 'https://192.168.1.101/api/WBhm7KR52YMWVnDIz9HMeqjHC2VZytaCVmV8YP3C/groups/Schlafzimmer/action'

def LightsOn():
    requests.put(urlLiOn, data = '{"on":true}', verify=False )
    
    sleep(100)

def LightsOff():
    requests.put(urlLiOff, data= '{"on":false}', verify=False)
    sleep(100)
```

I want to turn on my Lights with the requests on the raspberry Pi 4. I use Tkinter to create a GUI.
Problem:
I just can execute one command (LightsOn, LightsOff) and then my programm crash.
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '192.168.1.101'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
warnings.warn( Pls help How can I skip this error message or prevent it? What do I do wrong?

Comment: `http://` instead of `https://`!?

Comment: It might be crashing because of the `sleep` command. But can you use `http://` instead of `https://` in the URLs there?

Comment: Oh. It was the sleep command that caused the shut down and the https caused the error. It is still weird because everyone uses https. but it works :) Thank you guys.

Comment: "Everyone uses https" - who? Where? For communicating with a local IP you area almost never using https.